# Understanding How To Add Parsed Data To A Dictionary (Swift)

Tags: swift, dictionary

I think this may be a rudimentary question, but I'm having a really hard time grasping the concept of *dictionaries* in Swift.  I'm trying to get the contents of a XML-based web service, parse two specific fields and set them as Strings (one called "fileName" and one called "fileType"), then add these strings to a dictionary (lets call the dictionary "files").  I'd like to inevitably be able to print `files.fileName!` or `files.fileType!` later in my app to refer to a given instance.

Here is the code I am working with;

```
//MARK
func getData(theURL: String) {

    //Define the passed string as a NSURL
    let url = NSURL(string: theURL)

    //Create a NSURL request to get the data from that URL
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

    //Begin the NSURL session
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)

       //I think this is wrong
        var files = [String]()

        for elem in xml["XmlResponse"]["object"] {
            let fileName: String? = elem.element?.attributes["name"]!
            let fileType: String? = elem.element?.attributes["type"]!

            //I also think this is wrong
            let file = String(fileName: fileName, fileType: fileType)
            self.files.append(file)

            print(self.files)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }   
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

In a previous iteration, I was using `var files = [FileData]()`, *FileData* being a custom class I created to hold the fileName and fileType strings.  Is that the only way to do this?  I feel as though I'm missing a simple premise; I know how to gather the data (and the XML parsing *is* working), but I do not quite grasp how to add it to a simple dictionary which can be called later.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are creating with `var files = [String]()` is an Array, not a Dictionary.
To get what you want in Swift, you would need to create a Dictionary and then add your key value pairs using subscript syntax:

```
var files = [String: String]()
...
files["fileName"] = fileName
files["fileType"] = fileType
```

To access the Dictionary, you can use the same subscript syntax:

```
if let fileName = files["fileName"] {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a mapping from a key to a value. In your case you have the keys `fileName` and `fileType`. And you want to store an actual file name and file type under those keys so that you can access them with their respective key. This far better [explained by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113) than I am able to.

Following code should do what you want:

```
// Defining the dictionary and initializing an empty dictionary.
var files: [String: String] = [String: String]()

func getData(theURL: String) {
  // snipped a lot of your code

  //I think this is wrong
  var files = [String]() // Yes, this is wrong! See above.

  for elem in xml["XmlResponse"]["object"] {
    let fileName: String? = elem.element?.attributes["name"]!
    let fileType: String? = elem.element?.attributes["type"]!

    // Here you store your values in the dictionary
    files["fileName"] = fileName
    files["fileType"] = fileType

    print(self.files)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }   
  }
}
```

You access the values like this:

```
let actualFileName = files["fileName"]
let actualFileType = files["fileType"]
```